# Get a file/directory path from a string that contains other data

Tags: c#, string

How would I get the directory and filename from the following string using C#:

string test = "test@test.com, snap555.jpg, c:\users\test\desktop\snap555.jpg";

I only want to be able to get the "c:\users\test\desktop\snap555.jpg" from the string and turn it into another string.

The characters before the "," will always be different and different lengths such as: "bob@bob.com, x.txt, c:\users\test\desktop\x.txt"

What is the easiest way to do this in c#?

Thanks.

t

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the comma delimiter does not appear in the first part, you can use:

```
string pathName = test.Split(',')[2];
```

If that space after the comma is a problem and assuming that the first part never has spaces, you can use:

```
char[] delims = new char[] { ',', ' '};
string pathName = test.Split(delims, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[2];
```

This example assumes you always want the **third** item, as mentioned in your question. Otherwise, change the 2 in the examples above to the correct index of the item you want. For example, if it should always be the last item, you can do:

```
char[] delims = new char[] { ',', ' '};
string[] items = test.Split(delims, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
string pathName = items[items.Length-1];
```

Answer (score 2):

If there's always going to be a comma there you can use

```
string test = "snap555.jpg, c:\users\test\desktop\snap555.jpg";
string[] parts = test.Split(',');
```

Then get whatever you need from the parts array.